# Create interface using enum keys in Typescript

Tags: typescript, enums, interface

I want to use my enum to make an interface.

Just because one should change and the other one also needs to be changed.
I want to change the code more closely.

The enum's key is the same Interface's Key.

```js
export enum SmsReplaceKeyEnum {
  STAY_DATE = "%STAYDATE%",
  STAY_DATE_YMD = "$STAYDATEYMD%",
  ROOMTYPE_N_COUNT = "%ROOMTYPENCOUNT%",
  BOOKERNAME = "%BOOKER%",
  TOTAL_PRICE = "%TOTALPRICE%"
}

interface IPareser {
  STAY_DATE: string;
  STAY_DATE_YMD: string;
  ROOMTYPE_N_COUNT: string;
  BOOKERNAME: string;
  TOTAL_PRICE: string;
}
```

I also have this one

```
export const SmsReplaceKeyEnumKeys = [
  "STAY_DATE",
  "STAY_DATE_YMD",
  "ROOMTYPE_N_COUNT",
  "BOOKERNAME",
  "TOTAL_PRICE"
];
```

I tried

```
interface IPareser {
  [key in SmsReplaceKeyEnumKeys]: string;
}

interface IPareser {
  [key keyof SmsReplaceKeyEnumKeys]: string;
}
```

The final goal is to create an object's type with all the keys in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) syntax inside interface declaration in TS (now, up to version 3.5). You can make the desired type directly from your enum like this:

```
type Parser = {
  [K in keyof typeof SmsReplaceKeyEnum]: string;
}
```